# How to make custom login in django

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-forms

i am very new in python django.i had create a register page now i want to make login.i have written code for login but when i want to get  the data which is posted by login from is NOne.
my code is

```
def login_success(request):

    username=request.POST.get('email')
    password=request.POST.get('password')
    print "inside loginview"
    user =authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    print "username is",username
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)


            # return render(request,'loginsuccess.html',{})
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/')

        else:
            state="your account is not active"

    else:
        state="username or password is incorrect"
    print "username",username

    return render(request,'login.html',{})
```

i am getting NOne values in username and password

my models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):

    first_name=models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True ,null=True)
    last_name=models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True ,null=True)
    password=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email=models.EmailField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.first_name or u''
```

my login template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Is anyone getting tired of repeatedly entering the header over and over?? -->
        <title>Rango</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Login to Rango</h1>

        <form id="login_form" method="post" action="/loginsuccess/">
            {% csrf_token %}
            Username: <input type="text" name="username" value="" size="50" />
            <br />
            Password: <input type="password" name="password" value="" size="50" />
            <br />

            <input type="submit" value="submit" />
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update 1:**

First of all  `UserProfile` you created is not the correct way... by default django has the `User` modal

So please remove the UserProfile class from your models.py but if you wish to add additional field then extend with ForeignKey like

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    phone_number = models.IntegerField()
```

**Answer**

Your form method is `post` so get the post values in views like this

```
def login_success(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # do your code here
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
```

write your html like this

```
   <form id="login_form" method="post" action="">
        {% csrf_token %}
        Username: <input type="text" name="username" size="50" />
        <br />
        Password: <input type="password" name="password" size="50" />
        <br />

        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
```

Comment: I have tried this also. but not working

Comment: Can you empty  the action attribute on the form  and try again with same ? and also in your modified code edit the `request.POST.get('username')` please

Comment: i am getting what r u saying

Comment: ok..its working perhaps.

Comment: Oh is that working then please give the accepted answer ..

Comment: it is partially working.now it is reurning username and pass but login in not done

Comment: it is not entering inside if or else

Comment: authentication is not working

Comment: okay...we will debug that also ...

Comment: I have huge doubt `WHY DO YOU HAVE CUSTOME UserProfile ?`

Comment: then what can i do for it

Comment: please see my answer now

Comment: i do not want to use User dafault class

Comment: yeah.. but you can extend that as I suggested.... because password field is saving as plain text. So hackers can easily access your password. so try to use django default user more safe...

Comment: i will do that in my project actually this is demo ,my authentication is not working please help me why it is not woriking please have a look on my code.Only username and password returned but authentication is not done

Comment: can you tell me one more thing how you create the user ?

Comment: i have just write a register method for that

Comment: okay from there how you save the password ? bcse saving password in plain text doesn't help.. if the password is plain text authenticate will return always None...

Comment: i am saving password as plain text

Comment: now what should i do

Comment: @cpverma Your current method doesn't run when password as textfield. And saving password as Hash required multilevel programming. I suggest you to go with Django default User modal and if you wish to store other than default User field then extend as I suggested. There is no other way...

Comment: Hi.. Do you have the source code in github.. I will look the code and try to answer ..