# Authentication is not working for custom authentication

Tags: python, django, authentication

I want to make custom login page in Django. I can successfully register user but when I want to login it did not get log in.

My `views.py` for login:

```py
def login_user(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        print username
        print password

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user:
            print "rrrrr"
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/')
            else:
                return HttpResponse("Your Rango account is disabled.")
        else:
            print "Invalid login details: {0}, {1}".format(username, password)
            return HttpResponse("Invalid login details supplied.")
    else:
         return render_to_response('login.html', {}, context)
```

For registration I had write this code:

```py
def register(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    registered = False
    print "inside register view"
    if request.method == 'POST':

        profile_form = ProfileForm(data=request.POST)
        if profile_form.is_valid():

            profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)

            profile.save()
            registered = True
        else:
            print profile_form.errors
    else:
        profile_form = ProfileForm()

    return render_to_response(
            'register.html',
            {'profile_form': profile_form, 'registered': registered},
            context)
```

My `models.py`:

```py
class Profile(models.Model):
    # user=models.OneToOneField(User)
    username=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    first_name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email=models.EmailField()
    contact=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    password=models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username or u'
```

When I supply `username` and `password` it accepts the email and pass it but always go into the *else portion*: `Invalid login details`. It is not going into the *if condition*. How can I make working this?

Comment: It sounds like `user` is `None` because the authentication details are incorrect. What error are you seeing (if any)? What are your `print` statements showing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make custom login in django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36570082/how-to-make-custom-login-in-django)

Comment: Please follow as I [suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36570616/3762142) otherwise include the code of  "how you create the user "  maybe someone will answer your question. I suspect that you are saving the password as plain text...

Comment: i did not getting any error.it just execute else part

Comment: @Raja Simon i made login with default user class , but now i want to do login with my own model

Comment: If then please include the code of `register` view function please...

Comment: why this line is not getting execute         user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

Comment: can you print the password...! if password is plain text then user always None.

Comment: @RajaSimon i have update my question

Comment: @RajaSimon , maybe I'm misunderstanding you...but `authenticate()` [works fine with a plaintext password](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.authenticate). Perhaps you're referring to the stored value in the db being plaintext?

Comment: @rnevius thanks for the input.. I'm wrong...

Comment: So please help me how can i login  when i did not want to use default User model of django

Comment: You **must not** do your authentication like this. You are storing passwords as plain text, which is incredibly insecure. If you want a custom user, there is a [full example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example) in the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you don't store any data in `django.contrib.auth.models.User` your should be something like this:

**models.py**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    contact = models.CharField(maX_length = 50)
    # User class contain other fields that you need.
```

**forms.py**

```
class UserForm(forms.Form):
    class Meta:
        model = User

class ProfileForm(forms.Form):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
```

**registeration code:**

```
def register(request):
    # ...
    # Your codes here

    profile_form = ProfileForm(data=request.POST)

    # Add this line:
    user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST)

    if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
        user = user_form.save()
        user.set_password(user.password)
        user.save()

        profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
        profile.save()
        registered = True
    else:
        print profile_form.errors
        print user_forms.errors
else:
    profile_form = ProfileForm()
    user_form = UserForm()

return render_to_response(
        'register.html',
        {'profile_form': profile_form, 'user_form':user_form 'registered': registered},
        context)
```

You can find more Django official  User fields [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/)

Comment: it is when i want to use User Model.If want to use only  Profile form then how can i perform same process

Comment: If you are searching for a way to use Django `authentication/login/logout` I offer you the structure explain above. But if you want to customize authentication in your app can see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/)